# what does " which way does this go, now?" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I am reading a play, in a coversation one of characters refered to table setting and ask " which way does this go, now?" what is that about? about eating ? or cleaning the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In table setting, dishes, glasses and cutlery are arranged in certain conventional patterns. How these items are placed can be referred to as *how they go*.

One of the definitions of *[go](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/go)* is

> (Of a thing) lie or extend in a certain direction [*Oxford Dictionary Online*]

In particular, cutlery is often placed in a certain order, on a certain side, next to other specific cutlery and, in the case of knives, with the edge facing a certain way.

*That's the way they go.*